# I don't understand why my Python code is not correct for this simple problem?

Tags: python

Problem is the following (source: Codingbat):

*"You are driving a little too fast, and a police officer stops you. Write code to compute the result, encoded as an int value: 0=no ticket, 1=small ticket, 2=big ticket. If speed is 60 or less, the result is 0. If speed is between 61 and 80 inclusive, the result is 1. If speed is 81 or more, the result is 2. Unless it is your birthday -- on that day, your speed can be 5 higher in all cases."*

The code I wrote is the following, I don't understand why it is not correct:

```
  def caught_speeding(speed, is_birthday):
  if is_birthday:
    delta = 5
  delta = 0
  if speed + delta <= 60:
    return 0
  if speed + delta >= 61 and speed + delta <= 80:
    return 1
  if speed + delta >=81:
    return 2
```

Can please someone explain why the code is not correct?

Comment: Set delta=0 before the is_birthday statement. The current code will always reset the delta variable to 0 regardless of the result. Also instead of speed + delta >=61 do > 60 to catch every standard integer. Otherwise (60-61) will not be in the logic. Same case with 80-81

Comment: At first glance, you're always assigning delta to 0, you should have the birthday condition after you declare delta

Comment: "it is not correct" - what exactly does it mean? If you get an error, please include the complete error traceback in your question. If you don't get the expected output, provide well chosen, hard-coded input and the corresponding actual vs expected output.

Comment: The code is not correct according to CodingBat. In fact they say that when the following function is executed it will not return the expected value: caught_speeding(85, True)

Comment: In addition to setting `delta = 0` _before_ the `if` statement, you'll want to compare `speed - delta`, not `speed + delta` - otherwise, 56 mph would put you _over_ the speed limit on your birthday (56 + 5 = 61)

Comment: Not my downvote, but you are expected to try to debug this yourself. Figure out from the problem statement what the output should be for a couple of cases, and see if you get that from your code. If not, why not? Printing the values of your variables at various points during execution can often help you see where things are going wrong, or learn to use a debugger and use that to step through your code.

Answer (score 2):

A few possible issues:

1. Delta should be set in two ways: either 5 or 0.
2. If speed can be `float`, `speed + delta <= 60` and `speed + delta >= 61 and speed + delta <= 80` misses the situation when `speed` is between 60 and 61.
3. `speed + delta` should be `speed - delta`: say today is your birthday, you can drive up to 65 and not being fined, so 65 - 5 <= 60 is the right condition
4. I think it would be better to remove the last condition `speed - delta >=81` so that you program always returns something--otherwise it is possible your program returns `None` whose meaning is sometimes undefined.

```
def caught_speeding(speed, is_birthday):
  if is_birthday:
    delta = 5
  else:
    delta = 0
  if speed - delta <= 60:
    return 0
  if speed - delta <= 80:
    return 1
  return 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The birthday delta is a *discount* - you need to subtract it from the speed, not add it, eg.:

```
def caught_speeding(speed, is_birthday):
  delta = 0
  if is_birthday:
    delta = 5
  if speed - delta <= 60:
    return 0
  if speed - delta >= 61 and speed - delta <= 80:
    return 1
  if speed - delta >=81:
    return 2
```